# Removal of the "PUBLIC CV" notice on filed Stack Overflow Careers CVs

Tags: feature-request, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Public CV on careers page states it is a free service.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38178/public-cv-on-careers-page-states-it-is-a-free-service)

I'm loving the Stack Overflow Careers service in general and finally paid to file mine, but the core thing stopping me from linking people to my public CV is the "PUBLIC CV, A free Stack Overflow service." notice on the side.  If this were to go away for users who have paid to file, I believe more people would use it as their primary CV link -- I know I would.

Answer (score 1):

In the words of [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38178/public-cv-on-careers-page-states-it-is-a-free-service):

> But it's true -- the *public* CV page is free.

<sup>For all you closers, that link doubles as a duplicate link</sup>

The key part of that link is:

> We can't have any indication on the free public CVs that the user has paid to file, and be listed for private employer search. **Doing so would "out" anyone that has a public CV and happens to be looking for work.** Their current employers would be able to tell (by the absence of the "free public CV" tag) that they are not happy with their current job and seeking other employment.

Comment: Maybe they just want to show the difference better between the paid-ups and the free-listers. But the master question is right, that outs people who want to surreptitiously list their CV who also have a job.

Comment: Perhaps enable it as an option?

Comment: While that could be an issue for some people, I'd love to see it as an opt-in feature.

Comment: @Chacha102 - current employers should not be able to see employees in the private search, due to the magic of regex.